# Handling Nulls with QgsVectorLayer.getFeatures() and GeoDataFrame.from_features()

Tags: pyqgis, geopandas, convert, null, geodataframe

I am trying to convert selected features in a `QgsVectorLayer` to a `GeoDataFrame`. The input layer contains values including nulls across multiple floating, integer or string columns.

For Example:

[image]
[image]
When I use:

```py
import geopandas as gpd

lyr = iface.activeLayer()
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_features(lyr.getSelectedFeatures(), crs=lyr.crs().authid())
gdf.dtypes
geometry     geometry
FID             int64
Yield          object
DateStamp      object
Session        object
dtype: object
```

it loads Nulls as `qgis.core.NULL` (or `QVariant`) rather than `np.nan` creating an object column. Trying to list all columns containing nulls returns

```
gdf.isnull().any()
geometry     False
FID          False
Yield        False
DateStamp    False
Session      False
dtype: bool
```

and you can't do `gdf.replace(qgis.core.NULL,np.nan)` because `qgis.core.NULL` (or `QVariant`)  is an invalid type.

What is the best method to load features from a `QgsVectorLayer` into a `GeoDataFrame` to allow for nulls while maintain column definitions as shown.

Comment: Is it possible for you to provide some test data? Can you please explain this part a bit more in detail *"while maintaining nulls and column types"* ?

Comment: Update question with more information.